# How to stop a DDoS attack that brought down my ISP

Tags: ddos, isp

I'm streamer and I guess I'm good target for DDOS'ers. Those bad people know my ISP (but they don't know my IP address - ISP changed that for me when the first attack happened). It's a small local ISP (but it's under a bigger ISP) and some guy started a DDOS attack on my ISP to stop my livestream. I tried to contact the attacker but he said "pay and I will stop" lol. I provoked him and he started an attack again (and he sent me the first octet of my or my ISP's IP Address (huh) an "DDOS method?" - DNSSEC and time: 3600sec.)

What can I really do? I'm not sure that the ISP will fix that.

UPDATE: Attacker doesnt know my IP but he know my ISP. Using that he can DDOS ISP (DNSSEC method). Finally he will cut ISP's internet and I will be affected by that too.

Comment: The attack must be handled upstream, i.e. at your ISP or even more upstream. You can't do anything yourself here, except contacting your ISP and asking for help.

Comment: Nothing you can do I'm afraid. Your ISP has to handle that.

Comment: I dont think they will help but I will try. When first ddos happened (my IP was the target - they changed my ip address) I started to using this Internet for streaming only (OBS was bound to this IP, game was using other Internet) and their advice for me was to use an antivirus / antimalware. Their site isnt good too: prosat.net.pl (but I dont know if it does matter)

Comment: Is your IP address dynamic or static? If any IP suits your needs to stream, why not use a VPN?

Comment: Going forward, you might want to consider live streaming from a larger provider.  AWS has live streaming solutions (see https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/live-streaming-on-aws/).  AWS will be a much more formidable target for your attacker than your local ISP.

Comment: @bsaverino Static but ISP can change that for me (they can change my IP when I request that). Will VPN fix my issue? My IP Address is safe, Im using that provider only for livestreaming (OBS only using that network interface, game using other network interface - mobile). That way I can stream in high quality while being un-ddosable (game is on mobile internet, they dont know how to ddos "mobile"). But as You can see the attackers found an "bypass" for that (they can ddos my ISP lol).

Comment: @mti2935 is AWS like ISP or what is this? If it's ISP it's not available for me.

Comment: OK I'm not sure to get it fully :) but still I was also thinking that you may change the way you stream -> indeed if you can host your streaming service elsewhere (like Amazon Web Services), it will address big parts of the issue. If you can't, then the remaining solutions are limited, especially if your powerful attacker can impact an ISP..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.